# Adding spark to jar causing errors

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to add some spark dependencies to Maven. Everything works as expected when I run my main class directly but when I try to package everything into a jar and run it, it fails with:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /home/user/IdeaProjects/Project/out/artifacts/Project/Project.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class updaters.Main
```

When I remove the spark packages from the jar, everything runs again. I have been over this backwards and forwards several times, the error only occurs when the spark dependencies are added to the jar (I am using intelliJ to do this, I am building the jar as a separate artifact not using Maven). It is nothing to do with the actual code being executed.

pom.xml looks like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The only problem that I have experienced, in terms of dependencies, was Jackson-databind...whose version I had to change to 2.6.5.

Comment: Not enough data for a meaningful answer. Please see how to create [mcve]

Comment: If I don't know what is causing this, how am I supposed to know what data is missing? I am sure the problem occurs when adding the above dependencies,  I have tested that is the case, I have included that information. It might help me more to know what is missing...rather than just telling me that I am missing "data".

Comment: You did not provide enough information in your question for other people to help you. Please read: how to create [mcve] . Namely: include relevant parts or your Gradle file, what target you execute, full error message that you get. Please copy and paste it from the terminal instead of typing it yourself.

Comment: I am confused, I am not using Grade...I am referring to my pom.xml...the above is XML, not Groovy. I will clear up the confusion and add the information you suggest.

Comment: Apologies, yes, `pom.xml`, not Gradle file.

Comment: do you refresh your IDEA project after you add dependencies? i.e. do you reimport it from Maven?

Comment: Are you using an uber JAR? https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html

Comment: Yes: Add dependencies to pom.xml -> import new dependencies -> Go to Artifacts (in Project Structure) -> export new Maven dependencies into jar -> apply changes -> build -> run -> error as above...and to stop the error, I remove from pom.xml, take the dependencies out of Artifact, and rebuild jar...and it works.

Comment: I am not using an uber JAR...but that seems to be referring to a jar built by Maven? I am building as a separate artifact and extracting the Maven dependencies into the JAR. So I am fairly sure there are no missing dependencies...I am not sure if I understood that correctly though.